# Regex: Allow anything after matched pattern

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
tel:+390243887034;abcd=0032;trunk-context=abcdef.de@test.test.com;user=phone
```

Using this regex pattern:

```
^((tel|telco)?(:\s*)?\+(E)?\d{4}49[@\w.\-\s]+(,|$)|(tel|telco)?(:\s*)?\+(?!E)[@\w.\-\s]+(,|$))+$
```

it could be a list with tel: telco: elements.
How do I update so once first element is matched, anything can follow?

Comment: match this: tel:+390243887034; also if Exxxx present, where x is digit it must be E followed by 4 digits, then allow anything after first element ie abcd=0032;trunk-context=abcdef.de@test.test.com;user=phone

Comment: That rule only exists if Exxxx where x is digit exists.
ie then it must be like E123449

Comment: Also needs to match '+' in front of number

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might be looking for:

`tel(co)?\:.+?$`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your needs, but is this what you want:

```
tel(?:co)?:[^;]+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(tel|telco)?(:\s*)?\+(E)?\d{4}49[@\w.\-\s]+(,|;)*$
```

looks to do what I want so far

hmmm, maybe not